# Issue with dictionary definition and the openapi-generator

Tags: dictionary, openapi, openapi-generator

I try to generate Java (Spring) code for the following openapi 3.1.0 specification using the openapi gradle plugin version `6.2.1`

```
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: My-API
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /module:
    get:
      operationId: listModules
      summary: get modules
      tags:
        - Modules
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
           application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Module'

components:
  schemas:
    Module:
      type: object
      description: A module
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
        metaData:
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            type: string
```

The type `Module` should have a simple `id` and a *map*  from `String` to `String`. Using `additionalProperties` is the way to define maps according to the official openapi specification https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#parameter-object-examples

However, it fails with the follwing Exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Boolean` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]

It seems, `additionalProperties` expects to be a boolean, and indeed, if I change the line to

```
additionalProperties: true
```

the code generation succeeds and generates a `Map<String, Object>`. However, I would like to specify the value type. In fact, I don't want simple string values but a more complex types using

```
additionalProperties:
  $ref: '#components/schemas/MetaDataItem'
```

which fails with the same exception. What is wrong here?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the OpenAPI Generator. All of your `additionalProperties` usage examples are perfectly valid. Open an issue at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues, or check if there's an existing issue.

Comment: Yes, I will do so. 
I had a look before if there is such an issue. There are quite some related to `additionalProperties` but not exactly this issue. That's why I thought I am doing wrong somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with the very first line of your schema.  The openapi generator doesn't fully support openapi 3.1.0. Per the [readme](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#6---about-us) on their github:

> OpenAPI Generator allows generation of API client libraries (SDK generation), server stubs, documentation and configuration automatically given an OpenAPI Spec (both 2.0 and 3.0 are supported).

> We've gradually supported more features (e.g. oneOf, anyOf introduced in OpenAPI 3.0) in various generators and we will continue this approach to deliver something based on our understanding of user demand and what they want, and continue to add support of new features introduced in OpenAPI specification (such as v3.1 and future versions of the OpenAPI specification).

If you change the version to 3.0.* then you should se that the file is generated as you would expect.  I tried it myself using 3.0.3 and got a `Module.java` file with

```java
  @JsonProperty("metaData")
  @Valid
  private Map<String, String> metaData = null;

  public Module metaData(Map<String, String> metaData) {
    this.metaData = metaData;
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Just attempted to use 3.0.3 (per your recommendation) and I am still experiencing a similar issue.